# Redirect a indexed broken url to new one in python django- nginx server

Tags: python, django, nginx, broken-links

I have a python-django projet & it's hosted in AWS- nginx server. recently we changed the filename but whenever someone searching the old file (that is indexed in google) shows. it throws  404 error.
how will I redirect old url (indexed one) to new one.
ie:

`www.example.com/logistics-services-odisha` to `www.example.com/logistics-services-in-odisha`

we are trying it in robots.txt but no clue more. and we've not much experienced in this

Comment: robots.txt is not for that, if you want to redirect you can use .htaccess. as for fixing the google result you would need to enter the Google Search Console and requests a deletion of the old url. although I believe with the correct redirection in .htaccess and the correct error code you could make Google update the url. maybe....

Comment: nginx not support .htaccess..

Comment: In that case use tha main config file https://stackoverflow.com/a/32530504/5640517

Comment: See the next two threads: 1. [https://serverfault.com/questions/416825/attempt-to-www-rewrite-nginx-on-amazon-ec2-makes-my-domains-urls-unavailable](https://serverfault.com/questions/416825/attempt-to-www-rewrite-nginx-on-amazon-ec2-makes-my-domains-urls-unavailable) and 2. [https://serverfault.com/questions/775119/redirect-ec2-nginx-to-different-domain](https://serverfault.com/questions/775119/redirect-ec2-nginx-to-different-domain)